# jQuery - Targeting sibling elements through various dom levels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am currently working on a uni project and have the following problem in my code. I previously found the ID of my property via the $(this).siblings function. However, I recently redesigned my project's property output, so that each element is now wrapped in an independent div (for easier styling). However, this breaks the sibling’s relationship, as they are no longer siblings of each other.

First off here is the original code (which worked):

```
var sProperty = '   <div class="lbl-property">\
                        <label>id:</label>\
                        <div class="lbl-property-id col">{{id}}</div>\
                        <label>Address:</label>\
                        <div class="lbl-property-address col">{{address}}</div>\
                        <label>Type:</label>\
                        <div class="lbl-property-type col">{{type}}</div>\
                        <label>Price:</label>\
                        <div class="lbl-property-price col">{{price}}</div>\
                        <div class="lbl-propImage"><img class="propImg" src="img/{{images}}"></div>\
                        <div class="lbl-propImage"><img class="propImg" src="img/{{images}}"></div>\
                        <div class="lbl-propImage"><img class="propImg" src="img/{{images}}"></div>\
                        <div data-go-to="wdw-prop-map" class="fa fa-map-marker fa-fw btn-get-map link"></div>\
                    </div>';
```

Now this is my new code:

```
var sProperty = '\<div class="propContainer">\
                    <div class="row">\
                    <h2>Property title (static)</h2>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="PropImg row">\
                    <div id="headImg" class="lbl-propImage"><img class="propImg" src="img/{{images}}"></div>\
                    <div class="lbl-propImage"><img class="propImg" src="img/{{images}}"></div>\
                    <div class="lbl-propImage"><img class="propImg" src="img/{{images}}"></div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="row">\
                    <label>id:</label>\
                    <div class="lbl-property-id col">{{id}}</div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="row">\
                    <label>Address:</label>\
                    <div class="lbl-property-address col">{{address}}</div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="row">\
                    <label>Type:</label>\
                    <div class="lbl-property-type col">{{type}}</div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="row">\
                    <label>Price:</label>\
                    <div class="lbl-property-price col">{{price}}</div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="row">\
                    <div class="lbl-property-locLat col hidden">{{locLat}}</div>\
                    <div class="lbl-property-locLng col hidden">{{LocLng}}</div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="row">\
                    <div data-go-to="wdw-prop-map" class="propBtn fa fa-map-marker fa-fw btn-get-map link"></div>\
                    <div data-go-to="wdw-create-property" class="propBtn fa fa-edit fa-fw link"></div>\
                    <div class="propBtn fa fa-trash fa-fw btn-delete-property"></div>\
                    </div>\
                </div>';
```

A few things are moved around, however the biggest change is the divs. The order of the elements doesn't matter.

Now I am trying to perform various tasks on this code using the `lbl-property-id` however they no longer properly find the ID because of the changes to the DOM.

This is a simple example:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-delete-property", function () {
    var sIdToDelete = $(this).siblings(".lbl-property-id").text();
    console.log(sIdToDelete);
    var objectParent = $(this).parent().parent(); //This removes from page - two .parents are defined to work up the dom.

    var sUrl = "api-delete-property.php?id="+sIdToDelete;
    $.getJSON ( sUrl, function (jData) {
        if (jData.status == "ok") { //ok is returned from the server.
            console.log("Property deleted from database");
            objectParent.remove();
        }
    })
});
```

How do I target the `property-id` correctly now that I have changed the relationship between the elements. I got the `$(this).parent().parent();` to jump up a level in that regard. I just can't figure out how to adjust the `$(this).siblings` accordingly to once again get the ID.

Sorry for the long post.

Comment: I'd suggest copying the entirety of the JS variables and just including them as HTML snippets instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be fairly simple. I just needed to adjust the level i was targeting.

var sIdToDelete = $(this).parent().siblings(".idRow").children(".lbl-property-id").text();

First i target parent() which sends it up a level, then you go through the rows till you reach a row with a class of idRow (which contains the id) then inside that you look at the children of idRow which gives you the lbl-property-id.